# How do I use the Random Function In Scratch for a Gain and a Loss

Tags: mit-scratch

I want to use a random function for my code. I want the user to be able to click the Bitcoin symbol and lose anywhere from 30,000-50,000 dollars or gain anything from 30,000-50,000 dollars. I do not want to do something where it picks a random from -30,000-50,000. The number range there is too big and the chances of losing money are high. I want to have it be you either gain or you lose this much. How would I go about doing that. Simply put how do I use the random function to gain or lose money without putting such a huge range. [My Current Scratch Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UC6a.png)

Comment: Get two random numbers.  One from 30000 to 50000 and one from 0 to 1.  If the seoond one is zero then subtract and if it is 1 then add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MUCH *cough* *cough* cleaner method is:

`money += (random(0, 1)*2-1)*random(30000, 50000)`

All in one block!

Comment: That's fair. But it does become a little less readable, in my opinion. It's just harder to see what the code is doing at a glance.

Comment: Well, less lag? It's not that complicated.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
if random(0,1) is equal to 1
 money += random(30000,50000)
else
 money -= random(30000,50000)
```

There's a 50/50 chance of gaining, or losing, and then it will pick random.
Click the checkmark if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could write this in Scratch (For context, I am using the `scratchblocks` code format):

```
[scratchblocks]
when this sprite clicked
if <[(pick random (0) to (1))] = [0]>
change [money v] by (((-1) * ((pick random (30000) to (50000)))
else
change [money v] by ((pick random (30000) to (50000))
end
[\scratchblocks]
```

This is basically what it would look like in Scratch:

[image]

Hope this helps!